# How to send each element's ID from Ajax form to action?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, hidden, ajax.beginform

I need that, which item I click, to send it's `Id` to `GetProduct()` action. I used `hidden` element, but it does not work:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetProduct", "Product", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "getProductResult" }, new { id = "productForm" }))
    {
      foreach (var item in list)
      {
         <a href="#" onclick="$('#productForm').trigger('submit');">@item.Name</a>

        //this hidden always send '1', but I want to send item's Id
        <input type="hidden" id='product_@(item.Id)' name ="id" value="@item.Id"  />
      }

     <noscript>
        <input type="submit" id="sendButton" />
     </noscript>
    }
```

Where is my wrong? How can I send `Id` ?

Comment: Have you tried my solution mate? please let me know if you have any issue :)

Comment: I'm tring now, may be this part is not right some:  $('#id').val($(this).attr('rel'));    ?

Comment: here is the fiddler with the solution i proposed
http://jsfiddle.net/qNCXg/

Comment: i hope it is working fine for you now

Comment: 2 answers both was helpfull for me. I cannot decide to accept which answer. Thanks for both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the hidden input have name "id" and it is getting added number of time in for loop.
Hence it will not work..

don't submit the form directly on click of button. store the ID in rel attribute of button.
and assign its value to hidden variable when it gets clicked and then submit the form..

```
<a href="#"
   rel="@(item.id)"
   onclick="$('#id').val($(this).attr('rel')); ('#productForm').trigger('submit');">
@item.Name
</a>
```

putting the onClick code in separate function would be preffered though :)

Check this [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/qNCXg/)

Comment: Thanks for this. But i have many hidden fields. Form sends first hidden in every time.

Comment: yeah you would have many hidden fields as you are creating hidden fields in loop. put out the hidden field from loop

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

```
  foreach (var item in list)
  {
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetProduct", "Product", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "getProductResult" }, new {  }))
      {
     <a href="#" class="anchor" >@item.Name</a>

    //this hidden always send '1'.
    <input type="hidden" id='product_@(item.Id)' name ="id" value="@item.Id"  />


      <noscript>
       <input type="submit" id="sendButton" />
     </noscript>
     }
  }



<script>
$(function(e){
 $('.anchor').click(function(e){
   //get the parent form.
   var parentform= $(this).parents('form:first');
   parentform.submit();

  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: or use this.
     <a href="#" onclick="document.productForm.submit();">@item.Name</a>

Comment: Form submitting is not problem. it works. but, always send 1 value. Id=1. I want to send clicked item's Id.

Comment: issues was that each form have more than one hidden fields with name id.try it now i change the code.

Comment: I should change hidden fields. again value is "1" always

Comment: are you sure that the hidden fields have any other values ??

Comment: you remember me, I had  more than one hidden fields, I extract it out loop. not it works.